# Android: RequestFocus/Text changed

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently within my android application I am attempting to allow the user to enter data in 3 EditText boxes.

I want the focus to change automcatically from left to right when the data is entered in each.

I have done this for the first text box but I can't seem to add it for focus change between the 2nd and 3rd boxes.

How can I add this functionality?

Current relevant **Activity** code snippets:

```
day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterSpecificDay);
        month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterSpecificMonth);
        year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterSpecificYear);

String dayEntry= day.getText().toString() + "/";
            String monthEntry= month.getText().toString() + "/";
            String yearEntry= year.getText().toString();

@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if (s.length() == 2) {
          month.requestFocus();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Corresponding XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Enter Date to search..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificDay"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:hint=""
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLength="2"
        >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificMonth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="" >
        </EditText>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificYear"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:hint="" >

    </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchResultsDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="30"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=" Results..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> textView.requestFocus(); InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
>   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>   imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

refer docs:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

in afterTextChanged() do following changes:

> @Override
>       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>          if (s.length() == 2) {
>             month.requestFocus();
>             InputMethodManager imm =                                      (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>                      imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
>          }
>       }

Comment: Is this in place of the other 3 methods in my original post?

Comment: something like this

> > @Override
> >     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
> >        if (s.length() == 2) {
> >            month.requestFocus();
>            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
> >         getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
> >             imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
> >        }
> >     }

Comment: Can you please type you code as an Answer without the >> to make it clearer and that I am able to accept it ! Thanks